# Returning a function error in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I find this weird that whenever I am declaring variables in my controller and I want to return  a filtered value from my model I have to use a function. But when I try to call it using `{{#each}}` it gives me an error.

```
Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: The value that #each loops over must be an Array. You passed function () {
        return this.store.filter('entry', function(entry) {
            return (entry.get('entry_week') == moment().week());
        });
    }
```

My Controller

```
App.CurrentWeekController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    current_week: function() {
        return this.store.filter('entry', function(entry) {
            return (entry.get('entry_week') == moment().week());
        });
    }   
});
```

EDIT:
Route

```
App.CurrentWeekRoute = App.AuthenticatedRoute.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.store.find('entry');
    },
    setupController: function(controller, entries) {
        controller.set('model', entries);
    }
});
```

handlebars

```
    {{#each current_week}}
        {{description}}
    {{/each}}
```

So what's a better approach? I essentially have a lots of model instances and I need to filter them by certain conditions and display them separately.

In any case, how can I have a controller variable contain a filtered set of my model instances.

Comment: Can you paste the loop within the template and also the route and model hook?

Comment: Updated with route code and hbs code

Comment: I just submitted an answer that shows how you can filter the current weeks entries from from your route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare those functions as [Computed Properties](http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/computed-properties/) of the properties you are using to filter the items.

Additionally, you shouldn't have to use `DS.Store#filter`, but instead use [Ember.Enumerable#filter](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Enumerable.html#method_filter) on the `App.CurrentWeekController` model. The `model` property already contains a live collection of all your `App.Entry` records.

```
App.CurrentWeekController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    current_week: function() {
        return this.get('model').filter(function(entry) {
            return (entry.get('entry_week') == moment().week());
        });
    }.property('@each.entry_week')
});
```

One caveat is that the `current_week` array won't be updated on `moment().week()` change. You need some way of making sure `current_week` is recomputed when the week changes. Have a look at http://emberjs.com/guides/cookbook/working_with_objects/continuous_redrawing_of_views/ for some inspiration.

### Alternative approach

Assuming your model is `App.Entry`, define an `isCurrentWeek` computed property in your model definition, and use it in your template to show only those.

```
App.Entry = DS.Model.extend({
  // ...

  isCurrentWeek: function() {
    return this.get('entry_week') == moment().week();
  }.property('entry_week')
});
```

And in your template:

```
{{#each}}
  {{#if isCurrentWeek}}
    {{description}}
  {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: @MatthewBlancarte what do you mean set it within the setupController? Compute the current_week filtered array once in there? That won't be updated on `entry.@each.entry_week` change. Unless you mean something else.

Comment: I'm trying this, although there is no error. Nothing is showing up either. `{{#each current_week}} {{description}} {{/each}}`. That's the code i've tried.

Comment: I missed the fact that the OP was using Store#filter. I believe the right way is to use Ember.Enumerable#filter on the records collection (model) within the route controller. Edited my answer

Comment: Will you move your moment initialization out of the loop, the week won't be changing that often :)

Comment: @user1952811 updated my with an alternative approach. Defining an `isCurrentWeek` within the model definition can be a better approach if you will be using this filtering in a lot of places.

Comment: That can be a little bit of a pain depending on how your adapter likes to communicate and how your back end likes to sanitize params, but computed properties on the model can be really powerful stuff. +1

Comment: Panagiotis, fun different approach, it still is duplicating effort in the week creation, you're having to calculate the week in each model's instance.  It could be a static value on each instance, or changed to a computed.  `isCurrentWeek: Em.computed.equal('current_week', moment().week()),` http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/702/edit  I'll gladly revert my downvote if you'll correct the repetition.

Comment: @kingpin2k I think the bigger issue is that the CP won't be recalculated on week change. The argument that the week isn't changing that often is not valid. So users would have to remember to reload the app on Sunday midnight? What if the requirement was `moment().hour()`? I'm not saying that calculating `moment().week()` each time solves it in any way, but in the end the app will need to recalculate `moment().week()` every X seconds/minutes/hours, and trigger recomputation of the CP.

Comment: So you recommend paying the penalty without the benefit of it handling cross weeks?  In the context of a SPA they rarely are crossing weeks.  If they were crossing weeks, then you'd still want to have a single location supplying the current week, and make all of the properties dirty based off of that property, not have every instance keeping track of the what week it is.

Comment: @kingpin2k you are arguing with stuff I haven't said. The focus of the question was as basic as filtering an array and listing the items in the template. Your argument was "week isn't changing that often". I'm saying this is incomplete implementation, as pointed out in my answer - the code will eventually need to change to account for hour/day/week changes. Yes, with a single place to monitor hour/day/week that triggers CP recomputation (in a similar approach with the link I provided).

Comment: I'm arguing with your code.  Recommending inconsistent and non-performant code, then saying it won't work unless you change your code is a pointless recommendation.  Here's some code that won't work consistently, but over here is a place that talks about a way where you could fix it.  No worry though, if you want to keep your recommendation I'll quit arguing with you.

Comment: @kingpin2k I guess we have different views about the point of SO. You downvoted my answer because you spotted a performance improvement and at same time you posted an identical answer - only difference is using filterBy instead of filter. My answer isn't trying to give solutions to every possible problem that the question's code might have. But in the end its better to point out some problems and give directions to fix them, than never mentioning them or wrongfully arguing they rarely happen ("In the context of a SPA they rarely are crossing weeks").

Comment: identical except mine is more idiomatic, more performant, and more consistent.  True that, you're correct.

Answer (score 2):

You can empty your controller and then update your route to this:

```
App.CurrentWeekRoute = App.AuthenticatedRoute.extend({
    model: function() {
        var current_week = moment().week();
        return this.store.filter('entry', function(entry) {
            return entry.get('entry_week') == current_week;
        });
    }
});
```

Now, just because you have this code here does not mean that something will show up. Your filter may not be working as you expect.

You may want to do this in your hbs file:

```
{{#each current_week}}
  {{description}}
{{else}}
  <p>No entries this week.</p>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: I need to be able to add entries and so they should be showing up. So I guess i'll need a live collection.

Comment: @user1952811 I believe my updated answer will work. If the model updates, it should render. You can just filter straight from the route model because it looks like those are the records you want to work with on this route anyways?

Answer (score 1):

I wanna jump on the bandwagon of adding a million good answers :)  I recommend using `filterBy`, quick and clean.

```
App.CurrentWeekController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    current_week: function() {
        return this.filterBy('entry', moment().week());
    }.property('@each.entry_week')
});
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/702/edit